# What is wrong with entity class on my code?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have no idea why I see this error on my code.

I was tryed almost everything but there is still error

(This is not a part of problem description but i need to add some more text so i add this stupid comment to can update me post :/.
This is still not enought but i have no idea what more about it i can say and probles is fixed (in the comments is answer))

Code:

```
package com.example.carsharing.repository.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;



@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Car {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "ID")
  Long ID;
  @Column(name = "car_name")
  String carName;
  @Column(name = "company_id")
  Long companyId;



  public Car(long ID, String carName, long companyId) {
      this.ID = ID;
      this.carName = carName;
      this.companyId = companyId;
  }
}
```

````
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation
> report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
> 2023-07-21T17:00:49.296+02:00 ERROR 3872 --- [           main]
> o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
> 
> **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carRepository' defined in
> com.example.carsharing.repository.carRepository defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on Main: Not a managed type: class
> com.example.carsharing.repository.entity.Car**    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941)
> ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
> ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
> ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436)
> ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
> ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
> ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
> ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> com.example.carsharing.Main.main(Main.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
> **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.carsharing.repository.entity.Car**     at
> org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:192)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:467)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:97)
> ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]     at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:80)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317)
> ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279)
> ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245)
> ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114)
> ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285)
> ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]     ... 15 common frames omitted ```
````

Comment: Questions on SO are expected to be self contained. Do not post link to your repository, instead edit question to add the problem class as well formatted text (should be `Car` in this case).

Comment: is your class com.example.carsharing.repository.entity.Car annotate wit @Entity?

Comment: Please include a [mre] **in the question itself** - don't just link to your entire code offline. If the link goes dead, the question will become incomprehensible to future readers. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow questions are supposed to help everyone who has a similar problem (not just you).

Comment: In case `Car` is annotated with `@Entity`, please ensure that it uses the correct `Entity` annotation (for spring-boot `2.x`, it should come from package `javax`; for spring-boot `3.x`, it should come from package `jakarta`).

Comment: @Turing85 We should probably wait for the OP to [edit] the question before answering (even in the comments): [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine you mean... I should... moderate?

Comment: @Turing85 Good point, not until the strike is over :) Almost forgot myself for a second...

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine Thanks for this coment in future i will post just code not link to github.

If someones will be readint this in futere i was wrong import, it should be package  jakarta and i was javax

Comment: Please don't just do it in the future, [edit] this question so that it doesn't become obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

In case Car is annotated with `@Entity`, please ensure that it uses the correct Entity annotation.

- for `spring-boot 2.x`, it should come from package `javax`
- for `spring-boot 3.x`, it should come from package `jakarta`